# How to use useMessage and useNotification in App.vue using naive ui?

Tags: vue.js

I am using naive ui.For using useMessage and useNotification we have to register message-provider and notification-provider in App.vue .
Look like this

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<n-notification-provider>
  <content />
</n-notification-provider>

import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useNotification } from 'naive-ui'

// content
export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const notification = useNotification()
    return {
      warning () {
        notification.warning('...')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

we can use notification and massage content.vue.However how can I use notification and message
in App.vue

Answer (score 1):

The `provider` must be on the upper layer of `use`. You can refer to: https://github.com/Talljack/naive-ui-provider